# How to put some div elements inside a main div element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's an example:

```
<div class="main"> </div>
<div class="main2"> </div>


<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
<div class="sub"> content </div>
```

I want all the div's that obey the '2n-1' equation to be inside main div, and all the div's that obey the 2n equation to be inside the main2 div.

I tried with css nth-child but I couldn't :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Traditional question: what have you tried so far? What are the problems you encountered?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.  Good luck 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly :

```js
const subs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub')
const main = document.querySelector('.main')
const main2 = document.querySelector('.main2')
for (let i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
  if(i%2 === 0) {
    main.appendChild(subs[i])
  } else {
    main2.appendChild(subs[i])
  }
}
```

```css
.main{
  background: blue;
}
.main2{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> </div>
<div class="main2"> </div>


<div class="sub"> content1 </div>
<div class="sub"> content2 </div>
<div class="sub"> content3 </div>
<div class="sub"> content4 </div>
<div class="sub"> content5 </div>
<div class="sub"> content6 </div>
<div class="sub"> content7 </div>
<div class="sub"> content8 </div>
<div class="sub"> content9 </div>
```